# React não renderiza resultado deste código

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Estou estudando React e estou com um problema, mais precisamente na parte de estado, onde meu código não renderiza na tela. Neste caso tenho um `h1` e um `ul` e nenhum deles aparecem na tela, mas se eu apagar o `h1` aparece o `ul`, e se eu apagar o `ul` aparece o `h1`.

**Código**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.team = {Tname: "Dev's React"},
    this.names = {member1 : 'Caua', member2: 'Luna', member3: 'Henry', member4: 'Barry'}
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <h1>Hello Team {this.team.Tname} </h1>
      <ul>
        <li> Member 1: {this.names.member1} </li>
        <li> Member 2: {this.names.member2} </li>
        <li> Member 3: {this.names.member3} </li>
        <li> Member 4: {this.names.member4} </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque cada componente do React só pode renderizar *um filho* por vez. Se você reparar em seu código, o componente `App` está  tentando retornar dois elementos ao mesmo tempo: `h1` e `ul` – que estão "adjacentes" no código.

Você precisa, então, envolver esses dois componentes em um só. Para fazer isso, você pode, por exemplo, usar uma simples `<div>`. Uma outra alternativa, melhor, é usar o [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), que não irá imprimir nenhum elemento no DOM, servindo apenas para envolver múltiplos componentes em *um só*.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Lista</li>
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

---

Como observação final, vale dizer que você está definindo o seu estado incorretamente. Dentro de componentes-classe, o seu estado deve ser colocado dentro do objeto `this.state`, e não na própria instância (como você está fazendo). Para saber mais, leia o [guia sobre estado](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) da documentação do React.